# Using BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization for child collections

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a collection that has child collections and each of them can be updated from a different thread. How can I properly [enable collection synchronization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.enablecollectionsynchronization?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) for all of them?

My current solution is to create an interface `ISynchronized` that expose the object to lock when the collection is accessed:

```
public interface ISynchronized : IEnumerable
{
    object SyncRoot { get; }
}
```

And then subscribe to [BindingOperations.CollectionRegistering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.collectionregistering?view=windowsdesktop-6.0):

```
BindingOperations.CollectionRegistering += OnCollectionReg;

private void OnCollectionReg(object sender, CollectionRegisteringEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Collection is ISynchronized synchronized)
    {
         BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(synchronized, synchronized.SyncRoot);
    }
}
```

Are there pitfalls in this?

Comment: I don't see any pitfalls, and it looks good. You should put it as an answer to this question: [C# How to code EnableCollectionSynchronization for Collection of Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32403139/c-sharp-how-to-code-enablecollectionsynchronization-for-collection-of-collection)

Answer (score 0):

A possible issue is when a collection is bound multiple times.
The `CollectionRegistering` event will be thrown multiple times too.
And the `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` call will also be done multiple times for the same collection.
Altought, the documentation doesn't states if that is an issue.